# I want to make python code that opens a file reads first 2 lines and send resoults using discord webhook

Tags: python, webhooks

i have this core right now and it doesn't work if anyone could help it would be great

```
import aiohttp
from discord import Webhook, AsyncWebhookAdapter
a_file = open("path......")

lines_to_read = [0, 2] # line indexs starting with 0 so first line = 0 second = 1...

for position, line in enumerate(a_file):
    if position in lines_to_read:
        print(line)

with open('latest.log', encoding='utf8') as f:
    data = f
async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    webhook = Webhook.from_url(
    "https://discord.com/api/webhook........"),
        adapter=AsyncWebhookAdapter(session))
    await webhook.send(content=data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly your async with code is not properly indented - it uses data (equal to f from previous with clause), which already has been ,,closed'' (by exiting context manager scope). Try indenting your async with... code.

If you don't want to use  context managers, just use

```
data = open('latest.log', encoding='utf8')
```

but then you will have to properly manage file closing etc.